# internet explorer match() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, regex, knockout.js

I have a really weird error on IE.
I am using knockout custom validations. And one of my custom validations is to validate date.

function:

```
function isValidDate(txtDate) {
    var currVal = txtDate;
    if (currVal == '' || currVal == null)
        return false;

    //Declare Regex  
    var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/;
    var dtArray = currVal.match(rxDatePattern); // is format OK?

    if (dtArray == null)
        return false;
    /*continue of logic*/
}
```

This works great, when I run it first time. But then I do a redirect to server and return to the same page.

And the validation is called again at that point the problem begins.

I have a two snapshots of memory. They look identical to me. But there has to be some difference that I don't see or the match method is somehow broken.

The difference is not the dtArray == null that is the problem. You can try to run it in console. And it parse the dtArray correctly....

Both snapshot are on the same line ( if (dtArray == null) )

beforeRedirect:
[image]

afterRedirect:
[image]

Update. I solved my problem.

problem was that I was setting my observable property something like this:

```
var date = "1990-01-01T00:00:00";
var dob = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString();
masterModel.Dob(dob);
```

when I do it like this the match works fine now:

```
var date = "1990-01-01T00:00:00"
var dob = new Date(date);
var dobstring = dob.getDate() + "/" + (dob.getMonth()+1) + "/" + dob.getFullYear();
masterModel.Dob(dobstring);
```

if you want to see the difference run this on IE in console. My IE version is 11.0.9600

```
//because I am in UK my locale string is dd/MM/yyyy if you get different one this problem won't work for you!
var date = "1990-01-01T00:00:00"
var dob = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString();
var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/;
console.log(dob);
console.log(dob.match(rxDatePattern));

//vs

var date = "1990-01-01T00:00:00"
var dob = new Date(date);
var dobstring = dob.getDate() + "/" + (dob.getMonth()+1) + "/" + dob.getFullYear();
var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/;
console.log(dobstring);
console.log(dobstring.match(rxDatePattern));
```

Comment: You should post this as an answer, not as an update (after a grace period you can accept your own answer to your own question, too). Also, none of this would be necessary if you would work with date objects instead of strings - as I suggested.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, I agreed with you on that I should use library, but I think it is a bit overkill to introduce whole library for one field. But I will definitely look into it.

Comment: Well... I'd say use the proper tool for the job. Also, a plain text input for date entry is cumbersome and error-prone. For the sake of usability you should use a datepicker of some sort (jQuery UI is just one popular option, there are others). Once you have a date picker widget, you will get stuff like "actual date, not string" and "configurable format" for free. Think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Try simply checking for falsy values. The empty string, null and undefined are all falsy, there is no need to be more specific than that here.

```
function isValidDate(txtDate) {
    if (!txtDate) return false;

    var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/;
    var dtArray = currVal.match(rxDatePattern);

    if (!dtArray) return false;

    /*continue of logic*/
}
```

That being said, I strongly suggest you use a date library (most prominently: [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)) to do any date parsing, -calculation and -validation work. Don't roll your own regex when a fully functional and properly tested library has been written.

---

To think one step further, with knockout it's much easier to store an *actual date object* in an observable, so there is no need to parse any date strings at all, ever. You can also format it for display on screen any way you like, instead of limiting yourself/the user to a single format.

This way you would not need to do any date format validation at all. Either the observable contains a date - or not. For best effect use that together with a date picker widget (for example the one from [knockout-jqueryui](http://gvas.github.io/knockout-jqueryui/datepicker.html)).

View model:

```
this.exampleDate = ko.observable();
```

View, assuming jQueryUI + knockout-jqueryui:

```html
<input type="text" data-bind="datepicker: {
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy'
}, value: exampleDate" />
```